# How would you write this SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server

I need help creating this SQL update statement, the `Gift Narrative` column in the `DPGift` table with the `Narrative` from the `DP` table for that donor only if the `Narrative` contains the word “Verified”:

Comment: Hi Linda, your question is too broad for Stack Overflow's format.  Please try to formulate your question by showing sample input table data, the expected output, and then maybe describe the logic and/or show what you have tried so far.

Comment: The main form for an update with a join is: `update x set .. from x join y on .. where ..`. Then fill in the gaps.

Comment: Hi @Linda please provide you table structure and  your excepted output

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague, but if I am reading it correctly you will need to join the two tables, and as part of the join condition filter for values from the DP table where the narrative contains the word 'Verified'.

Sample below:

```
SELECT   DPGift.Gift
        ,DP.Narrative
FROM    DPGift
            LEFT OUTER JOIN DP
                ON     DPGift.<ID Field> = DP.<ID Field>
                   AND DP.Narrative LIKE '%Verified%'
```

You will need to replace  with whatever field joins the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update G Set G.[Gift Narrative]=D.Narrative
FROM DPGift G 
INNER JOIN DP D
ON G.[ID Field] = D.[ID Field]
where D.Narrative LIKE '%Verified%'
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) work, a good answer should always explain what the problem is and how it gets solved.